# Maple error - "illegal use of a formal parameter"

Tags: maple, gauss

I'M TRYIN TO CREATE A PROGRAM USING MAPLE FOR GAUSSING ELIMINATION BUT I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR

```
     Gauss := proc (n::posint, A::matrix, c::Vector) 
local a, i, k, j, p; 
with(MTM): 
n := linalg[rowdim](A); 
if det(A) = 0 then print('matrice*doit*etre*caree') 
else if det(A) <> 0 
then a := `<|>`(A, c);
 for k to n-1 do
 for i from k+1 to n do 
if a[i, i] = 0 then swaprow(a, k, i) 
else p = a[i, k]/a[k, k]; 
for j from k+1 to n+1 do a[i, j] = a[i, j]-p*a[k, j] 
end do;
 end if; 
end do;
 end do;
 else print('rien') 
end if; end if; end proc;
```

Error, (in Gauss) illegal use of a formal parameter

Comment: Post actual code in plaintext, not an image of code.

Comment: You've updated your question to now provide plaintext code for the procedure. Aside from the fact that it uses the deprecated lowercase `matrix` instead of the modern capitalized `Matrix`, it's not clear what your problem is. You are still missing the example of how you call it (and what you pass to it) that emits the claimed error message. If this is coursework then why copy code that seems written by someone else a long time ago? (It's very outdated.) If it's not coursework then why not use the stock routines already in Maple?

Comment: can u please take a look on this one it gimme the same exact error and yes it 's my own code

Comment: The first plaintext version you provided did not give me that error, when I tried it on a sensible input example (which matched results I got from `LUDecomposition`, btw). I won't try again until you provide an input example for your code, and the exact code lines in which you call it.

Comment: c := Vector([2, 3, 4])
A := matrix(3, 3, [4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 2, 1, 9])
Gauss(3, A, c)
and then it gamme illegal use of form ... like i mentioned earlier

Answer (score 1):

```
restart;
Gauss := proc(A::Matrix, c::Vector) 
  local a, i, k, j, m, n, p; 
  n := linalg[rowdim](A);
  m := linalg[coldim](A);
  if m <> n then
    print("matrice doit etre caree");
  else
    a := `<|>`(A, c);
    for k to n-1 do
      for i from k+1 to n do 
        if a[i, i] = 0 then
          a := linalg[swaprow](a, k, i);
        else
          p := a[i, k]/a[k, k]; 
          for j from k to n+1 do
            a[i, j] := a[i, j]-p*a[k, j];
          end do;
        end if; 
      end do;
    end do;
  end if;
  return a;
end proc:

c := Vector([2, 3, 4]);
A := Matrix(3, 3, [4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 2, 1, 9]);

Gauss(A, c);

LinearAlgebra:-LUDecomposition(<A|c>, output=U);
```

There were quite a few mistakes, so let's hope I get most of them.

I didn't bother doing 7. You should do it.

1. You cannot use `with` inside a procedure.
2. Your code uses commands from the`linalg`
   package, not the `MTM` package.
3. Ideally you'd use Matrix&Vector&LinearAlgebra
   (instead of your mix of matrix&Vector&linalg(.
4. Your procedure has `n` as one of its
   parameters, but inside it you also try to
   assign a value to `n`, the argument for which
   you passed in as the number 3. That's where
   your error message is coming from. You can't
   do that.
5. Several of you lines have just `=` instead of
   `:=` for assignments. The `=` does nothing.
6. The test against `det(A)=0` is wrong is wrong
   in several ways. I'll just say that it doesn't
   actually test whether the `A` is square.
   Compare the row & column dimensions if you
   want to test that `A` is square.
7. You should be using `LinearAlgebra`
   equivalents instead of the `linalg` commands
   commands `swaprow`, `coldim`.
8. You forgot to have your procedure actually
   return the Matrix `a`.
9. When your code calls `swaprow` is was not
   actually updating `a`. It was just throwing
   way the result.
10. It's a sin to not indent your code. It will
    lead you to overlook mistakes.